# how to pass data from first fragment to third fragment with using FragmentPagerAdapter android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter. I can pass data from first fragment to second fragment by using interface. But cannot pass data from first fragment to third fragment.

I have tried using shared preferences to pass the data, but I dont want to destroy the first fragment so I put viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2), then make the third fragment cannot get shared preferences.

Below is my class with extends FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;
private CharSequence[] title = {"Customer Details", "Activation Details", "Confirmation Details"};

public ActivationPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new Customer_Fragment();
        case 1:
            return new ActivationDetailsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new ActivationSummaryFragment();
    }
    return null;
}

//Return the number of pages
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

//Return the title of page
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
    return title[position];
}
```

e.g.
I try to pass to data from fragment one to fragment three, but failed with error java.lang.ClassCastException: fragmentone cannot be cast to fragmentthree

Below is fragment one:

```
public interface OnCustomerFragmentListener{
    void OnCustomerPassData(String data);
}
```

Below is MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void OnCustomerPassData(String data) {
    String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager_Activation + ":" + 1;
    ActivationSummaryFragment f = (ActivationSummaryFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    f.displayReceivedData(data);
}
```

Below is fragment three:

```
public void displayReceivedData(String message)
{
    Log.i(TAG, message);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you post first fragment code?

Comment: the interface should come from your Activity, and all the fragment could communicate through that. If you're using an interface where is the problem in implementing the same callback in all 3 of your fragments?

Comment: this is what I'm referring to :http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface

Comment: As for as I know from the code, you are trying to implement viewpager with three tabs, if your default pager at positon 0 is selected than pager at position 1 will also be generated by default. but when you will scroll the pager to position 1 , pager at position 2 will be also generated. and when you will scroll the pager to position 2 which is the 3rd fragment, pager at position 1 will be destroyed. So in order to pass the data you have to use persistant storage.like shared preferences or something else

Comment: @AbdulWaheed hi, my first fragment just create a simple interface like above question.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo You are right. After saw your comment and I review again my code, that just my mistake and I also solved my error. Thanks you so much. bro.

Comment: @Raza Hi, your statement is correct. In this statement "and when you will scroll the pager to position 2 which is the 3rd fragment, pager at position 1 will be destroyed", from my testing when I go to position 2, position 1 wont be destroy instead the position 0 is destroyed.

I have try used shared preferences, but I want prevent position 0 not destroy then I used viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2), then make position 2 wont not generated when I go from position 0 to position 1.

But anyhow I have solved my problem and thank you man.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!

Comment: the reason behind not destroying pager at position 1 , when you are at pager at position 2 ,is that, when you are at any new pager position, two new pager are always created along with this new position. one before that and one after that. For instance if you have total four fragments, with viewpagers, and by default you select the first one which is position 0 , it will always create the pager at position 1 with itself. so when you scroll the pager and move to 1 it will create the pager at position 0 and position 2. and when you will scroll to the pager 2 it will create pager 3 and 1.

Comment: but the pager at index 0 will be destroyed when you will at pager index position 2. because it creates only two nearest neighbors.

Comment: I am glad that you have solved you problem

Comment: @Raza ya, what are you said is correct. Thank for your statement bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link below show how to pass data between fragment with implement in viewpager.

https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments

The trick to pass the data to second fragment or third fragment or others is just changing the number at the end of the tag.

```
@Override
public void sendData(String message) {
    String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + 1;//<--change to 2, then can pass data to third fragment
    FragmentTwo f = (FragmentTwo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
    f.displayReceivedData(message);
}
```

Comment: hi i tried the same using interface and in the mainactivity i replaced with 2 but still i am getting error . can you say y. i am not able to figure

Answer (score 0):

You can set arguments when you are loading new fragment and can get arguments from that fragment in terms of bundle . You can set arguments when you have a call back of pager change listener. On listner change you can set arguments and when fragment is loaded you can get arguments. Hope this will help you. For further reference you can get help from google documentation of call back.

And second approach can be LocalBroadCast. on OnScrollChangeListener you can send broadcast.

Comment: I had implement fragment pager with tabs, so I cannot using the set and get arguments. Thanks you man.